# Is name reuse the only advantage of type classes?

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I am trying to understand type classes in Haskell.

I pose the question using a simple example:

Lets consider two datatypes, `A` and `B`.

Lets also assume that `a1` and `a2` are of type `A` and `b1` and `b2` are of type `B`.

Now let's assume that we want to define functions to check  if `a1` equals `a2` and whether `b1` is the same as `b2`.

For this we have two options:

**Option 1:**

Define two equality functions using separate names like this :

```
eqA :: A -> A -> Bool
eqA = ...

eqB :: B -> B -> Bool
eqB = ...
```

Now if we want to check if `a1` equals `a2` then we write : `eqA a1 a2`, similarly for `B` : `eqB b1 b2`.

**Option 2:**

We make `A` and `B` instances of the `Eq` typeclass. 
In this case we can use the `==` sign for checking for equality as follows.

`a1==a2`

`b1==b2`

**So, now the question** : as far as I understand the sole purpose of the existence of type classes is that we can reuse the function name `==` for the equivalence checking function, as shown in Option 2. So if we use type classes we do not have to use different function names for essentially the same purpose ( i.e. checking for equality).

Is that correct? Is name reuse the only advantage that type classes give? Or is there something more to type classes ?

**In other words**, given any program using type classes, I could rewrite that program to an isomorphic program that does not use type classes by giving separate names (i.e. `eqA` and `eqB`) to the overloaded function names (i.e. `==` in Option 2) that are defined in the type class instance declarations.

In the simple example this transformation would replace Option 2 with Option 1.

Is such a mechanic transformation always possible?

Is that not what the compiler is doing behind the scenes?

Thank you for reading.

EDIT:

**Thanks for all the illuminating answers !**

Comment: Is this is only use? Depends on how you look at them - IMHO the biggest advantage is beeing able to use them as constraints in generic functions (why this is so wonderful in Haskell see [Theorems for free here](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/wadler/topics/parametricity.html)). Implementation: think of it this way: if you use a TC `C` the functions etc. of this class are packed into a datastruture and this structure is passed around your code - so yes in a sense it's nothing more that what you suggested

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I am quite a begginer in Haskell and I am trying to put the pieces together. So it is a relief to know that type classes are only some sort of "syntactic sugar" that the user can create on its own. In other words type classes do not add to the power of the language, they only exist so that programmers can write more expressive code by reusing function names.

Comment: No - they add quite **a lot** to the power of the language! I was talking about the implementation. You can find lot's about them on the [Haskell Wiki](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Research_papers/Type_systems#Type_classes)

Comment: Power in terms of syntactic sugar ? I just would like to know what a Haskell program written using type classes can do something that a Haskell program written without type classes can NOT do.

Comment: It is possible to get rid of all overloading, but can be a lot of work.  Look at equality for lists to get an idea why.

Comment: "Regular" (Haskell 98) typeclasses are basically syntactic sugar, but if you include multi-param typeclasses and functional dependencies in your discussion, you can do meaningful computation at the type level, at which point typeclasses are no longer just syntax.

Comment: Thank you, that is a very good point !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type classes are syntax sugar, so there is nothing that you *cannot* do without them. It is just a question of *how hard* it would be to do without them.

My favorite example is QuickCheck, which uses type classes to recurse over function arguments. (Yes, you can do that.) QuickCheck takes a function with an arbitrary number of arguments, and auto-generates random test data for each argument, and checks that the function always returns true. It uses type classes to figure out how to "randomly" generate data of each individual type. And it uses clever type class tricks to support functions with any number of arguments.

You don't *need* this; you could have a `test1` function, and then a `test2` function, and then a `test3` function, etc. But it's nice to be able to have just "one function" which automatically figures out how many arguments there are. Indeed, without type classes you'd end up having to write something like

```
test_Int
test_Double
test_Char
test_Int_Int
test_Int_Double
test_Int_Char
test_Double_Int
test_Double_Double
test_Double_Char
...
```

...for every possible combination of inputs. And that would just be really annoying. (And good luck trying to extend it within your own code.)

Really, type classes make your code more high-level and declarative. It makes it easier to *see* what the code is trying to do. (Most of the time.) There are really advanced cases where I start to think maybe the design isn't quite right, but for the vast majority of stuff, type classes work really well.

Answer (score 4):

There is this very good article regarding type class which shows their desugaring process: https://www.fpcomplete.com/user/jfischoff/instances-and-dictionaries

So, yes, you could do without them, but you will need to have a different function for each type as you did in your question, or you will need to pass the instance dictionary explicitly as described in the article, while the type class do it implicitly so you don't need to bother. In many cases, you would end up with a LOT of functions with different names!

Nevertheless, your question leads also to the fact that type classes are often too much used when other patterns would solve the problem as well:
http://lukepalmer.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/haskell-antipattern-existential-typeclass/

Answer (score 1):

For the most part the answer is that type classes give you name re-use. Sometimes the amount of name re-use you get is more than you might think.

A Type Class is somewhat similar to an Interface in Object Oriented languages. Occasionally someone might ask "is the only purpose of an Interface to enforce contracts in APIs?". We might see this code in java

```
public <A> void foo (List<A> list) {
    list.clear();
}

List<A> list = new ArrayList<>();
List<A> list2 = new LinkedList<>();

foo(list);
foo(list2);
```

Both ArrayList and LinkedList implement the List interface. As such, we can write a general function that foo which operates on any List. This is similar to your Eq example. In Haskell we have many higher order functions like this. For example `foldl` can be implemented by more than just lists, and we can use `foldl` on anything that uses `Foldable` from `Data.Foldable`.

In OO you can use generics to do some really interesting abstractions and inheritance (e.g. in Java things like `Foo<A extends Foo<A>>`). In Haskell we can use Type Classes to do different types of abstractions.

Let's take the Monad class, which requires you to implement "return". `Maybe` implements `return` something like this:

```
instance Monad Maybe where
    return a = Just a
```

Whilst `List` implements return like this:

```
instance Monad [] where
    return a = [a]
```

Return, as it is done in Haskell, is not possible in a language like Java. In Java if you want to create a new instance of something in a container (say a new `List<String>`) you have to use `new ArrayList<String>();`. You can't create an instance of something because it fulfills a contract. While in Haskell we can write this code which would not be possible in Java:

```
foobar :: (Monad m) => (m a -> m b) -> a -> m b
foobar g a = g $ return a
```

Now I can pass anything to foobar. I could pass a function `Maybe a -> Maybe b` or `[a] -> [b]` and foobar will still accept.

Now of course this could all be broken down and functions could be written one by one. Just like Java could ignore interfaces and implement everything from scratch on each class of List. But just like the inheritance that's possible in OO once you factor in generics, in Haskell we can do some interesting things in Type Classes using language extensions. For example, check out http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Functional_dependencies_vs._type_families

Comment: Haha, that was silly. Was thinking Monad, wrote Functor. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Hmmm I don't really think that it is fair to draw an analogy between Interfaces in Java and type classes in (standard) Haskell. Why ? Because IMHO in Java there is no mechanical way to translate a Java program that uses interfaces to one that does not. Why ? Because interfaces allow dynamic dispatch at RUN time and if you have a program that relies on dynamic dispatch then you will need interfaces, IMHO. On the other hand I think there exists a mechanical way (read : algorithm) such that any Haskell program using type classes can be transformed into a Haskell program that does not.

Comment: @jhegedus, type classes give you dynamic dispatch, too, e.g., when used with existential types. The main reason that you cannot translate away Java interfaces is that Java's type system is too inexpressive to be able to do that, as opposed to Haskell's.

Comment: Existential types is not standard Haskell as far as I know, or is it ?